# Writing a matrix in R , by indices

Tags: r, matrix

I want to to create this matrix in R, but my codes gives me zero for all elements.

Where the diagonal is 1 and elements adjacent to diagonal is 0.25.
[image]

```html
n = 97
W =  matrix(0 , n,n)
diag(W)=1
for (i in 1:rowCount) {
  for (j in 1:rowCount){ 
  if(j==i){W[i,j] = 1
  } else if (j==i-1){W[i,j] = .25
  } else if (j==i+1){W[i,j] =.25}
 }}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? You code seems to work (assuming you change `rowCount` to `n` or visa versa).

Comment: the problem is that my codes does not work and gives zero for all elements.

Comment: Do you have `rowCount` defined elsewhere in your code? Right now that's not defined. Maybe that's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diag` to set diagonal elements to 1, and then use `row` `col` to set elements adjacent to diagonal as 0.25.

```
n <- 5
mat <- diag(1, n)
mat[abs(row(mat) - col(mat)) == 1] <- 0.25
mat

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,] 1.00 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00
#[2,] 0.25 1.00 0.25 0.00 0.00
#[3,] 0.00 0.25 1.00 0.25 0.00
#[4,] 0.00 0.00 0.25 1.00 0.25
#[5,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 1.00
```